# Springloaded Spring Boot hot reload

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I added springloaded as dependency in my project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I set as VM params:

```
-javaagent:C:\Users\myuser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\springloaded\1.2.7.RELEASE\springloaded-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar -noverify
```

Hot reload still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 0):

Based of the tag's I assume you're trying to use `Springloaded` with a `Spring Boot` app. To enable this with a Spring Boot application, you should include it as a dependency to to the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Further documentation can be found https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html#howto-hotswapping in relation to hotswapping,

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html#howto-reload-springloaded-maven